# Accepted article still not assigned a Volume or Issue number in a journal

Tags: journals, editors

One of my research articles has been published in one of the IEEE journals. The IEEEXplore page, the data of publication is mentioned as 29 March 2016, but the article has not yet been assigned to an issue. I enquired with the concerned people and below is the reply which I got from them.

> The Editor-in-Chief of the journal determines when a
>   paper is included in an issue. You can contact him directly to find
>   out when he plans to publish your paper. His contact information can
>   be found on Xplore. Thank you. XXXX

Should I write to the EiC about the article or should I wait till comes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do write, very politely, to the Editor in Chief. In most cases he just wants to pursue other topics or maybe wants to bundle your work with a similar one which is not yet 100% ready.

Rarely, though, even editors might make mistakes, and it is not impossible that your work had been involuntarily shelved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As suggested, I wrote to the EiC. They answered my query saying that it is estimated to get published in July 2017.  Thanks again.